# Как удалить не существующие сущности из коллекции при обновлении?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

В проекте на ASP.Net Core второй версии имеется сущность `Person` со связями один-ко-многим между сущностями `Email`, `Phone` и `Address`. В представлении, при редактирование персоны, сущности `Email`, `Phone` и `Address` добавляются динамически и без сохранения в БД.

#### Схема взаимосвязей в БД

[image: Связи в БД]

При сохранении персоны, вся информация сохраняется в БД без проблем: и персона, и добавленные адреса с телефонами. 
Проблема состоит с удалением, например эл.адреса. На стороне контроллера я получаю экземпляр `Person` с правильной `ICollection<Email>` (к примеру без удаленного эл.адреса), далее сохранение в БД происходит без ошибок, но в БД отображаются изменения только в свойствах персоны, т.е. эл.адрес не удаляется.

---

Поэтому в данный момент в контроллере делаю так:

```
var _emails = await _context.Email
    .Where(e => 
        e.PersonId == person.Id && 
        person.Emails
            .Where(i => i.Id == e.Id)
            .Count() == 0)
    .ToListAsync();
_context.Email.RemoveRange(_emails);
_context.Person.Update(person);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Но терзают сомнения, что делаю правильно ибо выглядит такой подход как-то "коряво".

---

Как правильно сохранять сущность со всеми переданными сущностями в коллекции? Есть ли способ автоматического удаления сущностей не переданных в коллекции связанных объектов?

#### Модель:

```
namespace ProjectNS.Models {
    public partial class Ctx : DbContext {

        public virtual DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Email> Email { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Phone> Phone { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            // Address и Phone пропущены для экономии места (выглядят аналогично)
            modelBuilder.Entity<Email>(entity => {
                // Описание свойств пропущено для экономии места
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Person)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Emails)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.PersonId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Email_Person");
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity => {
                // Описание свойств пропущено для экономии места
                entity.HasOne(d => d.CompanyNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Person)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CompanyId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Person_Company");
            });
        }
    }
    public partial class Person {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // ничего особенного
        public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
    }
    // Address и Phone пропущены для экономии места (выглядят аналогично)
    public partial class Email {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // ничего особенного
        public int? PersonId { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Контроллер:

```
namespace ProjectNS.Controllers {
    public class PeopleController : Controller {
        private readonly Ctx _context;
        public PeopleController(Ctx context) {
            _context = context;
        }
        // Другие методы пропущены для экономии места
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,...,Emails,Phones,Addresses")] Person person) {

            if (id != person.Id) {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                try {

                    // Вот здесь начинается "танец с бубном"
                    // для удаления несуществующих сущностей из БД
                    var _emails = await _context.Email
                                 .Where(e => 
                                        e.PersonId == person.Id && 
                                        person.Emails
                                              .Where(i => i.Id == e.Id)
                                              .Count() == 0)
                                    .ToListAsync();
                     _context.Email.RemoveRange(_emails);

                    _context.Person.Update(person);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) {
                    if (!PersonExists(person.Id)) {
                        return NotFound();
                    } else {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            ViewData[nameof(Person.CompanyId)] = new SelectList(_context.Company, nameof(Company.Id), nameof(Company.Name), person.CompanyId);
            return View(person);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Просто в цикле проходите и удаляете все лишние записи. Если запись хранится в своей таблице, то её надо ручками и удялять, кроме случая каскадного удаления, то есть удаляя пользователя можно удалить все емэйлы за раз без дополнительных операций.

Comment: о! способ есть. при откреплении email из колекции человека, будет обнулятся столбец PersonID. Значит можно потом пройтись по всем емэйлам и удалить те, что имеют пустой PersonId.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин проблема не в удалении, а при обновлении. Если изменяется к примеру `Email` у `Person`, то изменения сохраняются. При добавлении нового `Email` тоже всё в порядке. А при удалении связанных сущностей изменения не отображаются в БД. Насчет "открепления" можно по-подробней?!

Comment: Да, понял проблему. Тоже буду ждать ответов других участников :))))

Comment: Ну если email уже не ссылается на пользователя, то такие email-ы просто удаляются процедурой `db.Emails.RemoveRange(db.Emails.Where(x=>x.PErsonId == null));` Как у вас выглядит запись Email в случае если вы в том Person что он был, обновили коллекцию?

Comment: А если `public int? PersonId { get; set; }` убрать знак вопроса? Как раз этот знак вопроса  и говорит о том что может быть Email без человека, и это по-идее должно соответственно отрабатываться в EF, возможно без этого знака вопроса EF будет себя по-другому вести. Либо если его оставить то делайте как написал в прошлом сообщении.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин В случае обновления `Person` с коллекцией, в которой был удален `Email`, в БД никаких изменений нет. 

`Email` может также принадлежать `Company`, к примеру `contact@domain.tld` или `info@domain.tld`. Поэтому и указано, что ссылка может быть нулевой. Другими словами, удалять все эл.адреса с `PersonId == null` не вариант.

Comment: Так ну поэтому сам и не удаляется... В данном случае можно сделать проверку где и Company и Person = null. Но в вашем случае думаю лучше удалять вручную.